# How can I set python-mode.el shell completion like default inferior shell?

Tags: python, company-mode, repl

Autocompletion in `python-mode.el` opens another completion window with available completions. It looks like this[image]

But I need to use `company` completion like default inferior python shell
[image]

How can I enable this in `python-mode.el`? Or maybe I can use default inferior shell with `python-mode.el`?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Noticed so far: https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/1656757